# If I delete a Drive folder which contains a file that has multiple parents, does the file still get deleted?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

The question explains everything. But again, I need to know if it is safe to delete a folder (which contains hundreds of important files) that contains many files belonging to multiple parents (folders). Will deleting one folder delete the related files from all folders that reference the files?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out things like this is to test them we can do it using [APis exploerer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3)

**Setup test**

create new folder

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-application/vnd.google-application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
 "name": "TestDeleteFolder1"
}
```

New folder id is 181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX

Create a new file in that folder

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
 "name": "TestDeleteFileOne",
 "parents": [
  "181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX"
 ]
}
```

Gave me a folder on my google drive account with one file in it.

- Folder Id 181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX
- File in the folder Id 1EEYXRLIWD1_kbX3c8yYeY8duBSE_KeCVDUFSh9Sth7w

**Delete it**

Delete the folder

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Test results**

Try to get the folder

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

> "File not found: 181vifeF0eyd5J-8lzlYqJHSM1xbhPJFX.",

try to get the file

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1EEYXRLIWD1_kbX3c8yYeY8duBSE_KeCVDUFSh9Sth7w?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

> "File not found: 1EEYXRLIWD1_kbX3c8yYeY8duBSE_KeCVDUFSh9Sth7w.",

**Anwser**

If you delete a folder all of the files with in it will be deleted there will be no warning everything is just gone.